# ssh wait for script to finish

Tags: bash, ssh, nodes, rocks

I am using  the following script to start a process on a node.
from the main node:

```
for dir  in  n9 n18 n27 n40
do

node=compute-2-10

ssh $node "cd $dir ; nohup ./process.sh >  WATCHDOG-$dir &"

done
```

the thing is that when I connect to compute-2-10 I see no jobs running. I think that the problem is that the process can not be completed since bash doesn't wait for it to finish. Is this correct or do I need to do something else?

Comment: What happens if you omit the `&`? Does `ssh` block waiting for `process.sh` to complete, or does `process.sh` complete quickly and allow `ssh` to finish?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using something like

```
ssh $node "nohup myprogram > prog.out 2> prog.err < /dev/null &"
```

If you redirect all three I/O then this should not create any issue.

Comment: Well above works for me all the time, try following as well:
ssh $node "/bin/bash -c 'nohup ./kl.sh > prg.out 2> prg.err < /dev/null &'"

Can you also try by running a script having just sleep and 1 echo in infinite while loop. instead of your existing one.